# What is nnbd in dart?

Tags: dart

In https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_icons/changelog I see that

> Add README note that version 1.0.0 should be used until nnbd is on stable.

What is nnbd? and can you refer me to official doc?

Comment: it means Non-Nullable-By-Default look at [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/110) for more informations.

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety